# Page Not Found: "The page requested was not found"

Tags: facebook, mobile

We have configured the app in face book developer site.
It was working fine in all web and mobile browsers and in mobile fb apps as well.
But recently (May/June 2015), when we tested the app in "mobile app" like android mobile, its redirecting to the "Page not found" page with below error: "The page requested was not found", when we click the app in search window of FB app.
Debug log message is showing below error:
Exception during service
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:91)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:179)
    at

```
at 
at 
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:284)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:126)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:433)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:157)
at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:145)
at 

at com.facebook.http.executors.qebased.QeHttpRequestExecutor.a(QeHttpRequestExecutor.java:102)
at 
at com.facebook.http.common.RequestFlowStateController.a(RequestFlowStateController.java:124)
at com.facebook.http.common.FbRedirectController.a(FbRedirectController.java:100)
at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.c(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:350)
at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:317)
at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:304)
at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:248)
at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:464)
at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:567)
at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.b(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:270)
at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:18)
at com.facebook.search.service.GraphSearchServiceHandler.d(GraphSearchServiceHandler.java:90)
at com.facebook.search.service.GraphSearchServiceHandler.a(GraphSearchServiceHandler.java:62)
at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.f(BlueServiceQueue.java:388)
at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:61)
at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

We have enabled "Native or desktop app?" in Settings >>> Advance tab section in FB developer configurations.

Comment: it is working in android mobiles (Sony erricson) with fb app version as 2.3 and 3.9. But its not working in latest versions such as 4.0, 5.0 (34.0.0.x).

Comment: How are you accessing these pages? did you get your permissions reviewed after the v1.0 was deprecated?